# How to Pivot one columns multiple times?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

A table is

```
  ID  YEAR Name   Value

  1    2014  A     10
  2    2014   B    20
  1    2013   A     30
```

Want a table like below:

```
 ID  2014   2013   A  B
 1    10    20    40  0

 2    20     0    0    20
```

Bascially want to Pivot Value column for both Year and Name. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this with conditional aggregation:

```
select id,
       sum(case when year = 2014 then value else 0 end) as [2014],
       sum(case when year = 2013 then value else 0 end) as [2013],
       sum(case when name = 'A' then value else 0 end) as [A],
       sum(case when name = 'B' then value else 0 end) as [B]
from table t
group by id;
```

Comment: Is there any way to do this using pivot? as i have so many years and names

Comment: You have to create a subquery that puts everything in a single column.  Conditional aggregation is probably easier to implement.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way using `pivot`

```
SELECT id,
       Isnull([2014], 0) [2014],
       Isnull([2013], 0) [2013],
       Isnull([A], 0)    [A],
       Isnull([B], 0)    [B]
FROM   (SELECT *,
               Sum(value)OVER(partition BY Name) tot
        FROM   Yourtable) a
       PIVOT (Max(Value)
             FOR year IN ([2014],
                          [2013]))pv    
       PIVOT (Max(tot) 
             FOR name IN ([A],[B]))pv1
```

**[SQLFIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b5bb8/1)**